# Error al borrar un registro de la base de datos SQL server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

He intentado de estas dos formas.

`1`

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)// el id llega con toda normalidad
{
    db.Entry(db.Detalle.Find(id)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`2`

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) // el id llega con toda normalidad
{
    Detalle idar = db.Detalle.Find(id);
    db.Detalle.Remove(idar);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

y los dos me dan el mismo error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El código de usuario no controló System.ArgumentNullException
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=El valor no puede ser nulo.
>   Nombre del parámetro: entity
>     ParamName=entity
>     Source=EntityFramework
>     StackTrace:
>          en System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.Requires(Boolean condition, String userMessage, String conditionText)
>          en System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Remove(TEntity entity)
>          en SIGA.net.Controllers.ArqueoController.DeleteConfirmed(Int32 id) en C:\Proyectos\SIGA.net\SIGA.net\Controllers\ArqueoController.cs:línea 173
>          en lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          en System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          en System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>          en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>     InnerException:

Comment: Aparentemente `db.Detalle.Find(id)` te devuelve `null`. Te tocará averiguar porqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**no uses linq, usala de esta manera y seras feliz..**

```
 string query = @"Delete from Detalle where Id = @Id";

            SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(query, ConexionDB);
            cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Id", id);

            ConexionDB.Open();
            cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ConexionDB.Close();
```

Comment: ...Serás feliz hasta que te toque modificar algo en la estructura de la tabla. Y ahora tendrás que buscar en todo tu código para ver donde están tus cadenas SQL, cruzarte los dedos de que no se te escape uno, y ver cómo las puedes modificar individualmente sin errores, porque el compilador no te va a ayudar. Para algo existe Entity Framework. Simplemente botar EF a la basura cuando uno no entiende un error sencillo no me parece la mejor idea. Una opinión no más.

Comment: modificar algo en la estructura de la tabla??
antes de empezar con los proyectos existe el analisis, no es etico modificar la escructura cuando ya esta montado.

Comment: @sstan se que sabes mucho, me interesa tu metodo, necesito tu sabiduria

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar en la linea `db.Detalle.Find` con db.Detalle.FirstOrDefault aunque en este caso creo que es mejor `db.Detalle.SingleOrDefault` o simplemente db.Detalle.Single
referencia
[diferencia entre single find y firstorDefaul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485317/entity-framework-4-single-vs-first-vs-firstordefault)

prueba y miras como te va